# How to specify Where clause for each group from group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to group all data by column "Ico" and from each group (125, 130, 140) select only those, where column "ValidTo" is not NULL.

I have a set of data:

```
Id  Ico  ValidTo
1   125   NULL
2   125   7.5.2019
3   125   7.5.2019
4   130   20.5.2019
5   130   21.5.2019
6   140   NULL
7   140   NULL
```

So the result would be

```
Ico    ValidTo
130   21.5.2019
```

The result doesn´t have to be grouped and it doesn´t need to show only the maximum valid date (but it would be nice)

Perfmance is not an issue, the query is just for testing purposes to test if my several LINQ queries does the job right.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `not exists`

```
 select * from your_data t1
 where not exists (
    select 1
    from your_data t2
    where t1.ico = t2.ico and t2.validto is null
 )
```

This solution is not doing the group of the data. If you are really interested in the greatest per group you may use `row_number()` window functions

```
select *
from (
     select *,
            row_number() over (partition by t1.ico order by validto desc) rn
     from your_data t1
     where not exists (
        select 1
        from your_data t2
        where t1.ico = t2.ico and t2.validto is null
     )
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: Good job in figuring OP's logic

Comment: That was surprisingly easy.. I thought something like this would also select row where Ico = 125 excluding the one ValidTo = NULL row. So it seems to work, I´m just not sure how :) thanks

Comment: @Qirel the OP clearly stated that "The result doesn´t have to be grouped"

Answer (score 1):

One way of going about it is grouping by the `ico` column, and checking if the count of rows in that group is equal to the sum of non-null rows.

```sql
SELECT ico, MAX(validto)
FROM foo t1
GROUP BY ico
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN validto IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = COUNT(id)
```

- SQL fiddle shows it in action, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/61571/12

Comment: I would use:  `COUNT(*) = COUNT(validto)`, but the idea is the same.  This seems to more accurately capture the requirement that only one row is returned per `ico`.